# UNIX Command to list all the instances of weblogic running on a server

Tags: weblogic

I want the list of all instances of weblogic presently running on a server

Comment: `ps ax | grep weblogic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ps -ajx | grep java

or

```
ps -elf | grep java
```

This will give all java processes running, you can figure out weblogic process from there.

Comment: I'm able to list all the process that are stared with java command but i wanted the all instance names of weblogics,and process associated with particular instances -please help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ps command to list all processes and grep the output appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

ps -ef | grep java

It Displays the hole process of process status and PID's

kill -9 PID

It's kill the particular process forcefully

Use this very usefully and important case sometimes

Thanks

Comment: You can do it using ps command to list all processes and grep the output appropriately.